# How to set email receiver as a primary contact from Case?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365

When sending email from Case form (in Unified Interface) as Email reeiver is set Customer from Case. In old user interface this was Contact (primarycontactid). Is this configurable, and is there a suported way to set Contact as email receiver?

Thank you!

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you need to only set up the workflow for the account then you can build it in a way:

`{Primary Contact(Customer(Account))}` in your processes.

Comment: I'm wondering what is difference in these two solutions, both are out of the box functionalities.  But for unified interface it takes Account instead of primary Contacts. SO now the question is can this be changed somehow, without writing custom code/workflow. Thanx!